# Graphs with pairs of vertices connected by multiple edges

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a common name for this kind of graphs (directed or not)?

[image: a graph with multiple edges between a pair of vertices]

Thank you.

Comment: Another common name for such an object is a pseudograph.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as [multigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph).

Comment: Aha! Then it appears that the following theorem does not hold for multigraphs:" A connected undirected graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has even degree". Do I miss something?

Comment: It should be true for multigraphs too.  The only complication should be that loops (if any) need to contribute 2 to the degree of a vertex.

Answer (score 1):

They are known as Undirected Multigraphs.